# Windows program to "mount" a remote CMIS folder

Tags: windows, cmis

Is there any program that emulates a Windows filesystem folder or drive to show a remote [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) folder and its content, just like if it were present on the local disk?

I am not looking for a tool like [CmisSync](http://cmissync.com/) which synchronizes files.

I am looking for a tool that only pretends that files are on the local disk, but actually reads/writes everything to the server directly. That means that files will not be available when offline, which is not a problem - a bit like you can [mount a remote WebDAV folder](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/user_manual/files/files.html#using-windows-explorer) so that it shows in Windows Explorer and other applications.

Editing office files directly from this folder must work.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct solution **but** there is a japanese lib called [JDokan](https://github.com/sainaen/JDokan) (well, it's a Java wrapper over [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/)) which allow you to write file system extensions (in the same way Fuse allow you on Linux). As a Java developper, I guess it could be possible to write an implementation using [OpenCMIS](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) client lib to connect to server ...

Comment: I implemented your idea, see the detailed answer :-) Thanks a lot for the great tip!

Answer (score 2):

I implemented @Riduidel's idea, and called it [Aegif CmisDrive](https://github.com/aegif/CmisDrive). I made it open source.

[image: Aegif CmisDrive]

As the screenshot above shows, you can mount any CMIS repository as a drive. I tested it with NemakiWare and Alfresco.

Not everything works, but it is sufficient for my immediate needs. Anyone feel free to propose better software if available.