# Desktop CMIS explorer, real-time access without caching/synchronization

Tags: windows, desktop-client, cmis, metadata-editor

I want to browse the folders/documents that are on a CMIS server.
*([CMIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) is an interoperability protocol supported by Alfresco/Documentum/SharePoint/etc)*.

While CmisSync can be used to synchronize a folder recursively, here I just want to browse content, without synchronizing.

Unlike [Windows program to "mount" a remote CMIS folder](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/590/windows-program-to-mount-a-remote-cmis-folder) I don't want to "mount" the folder, and metadata edition is required.

Requirements:

- Navigate content of any CMIS-compatible server
- Create/delete/modify/move folders and documents
- Edit CMIS metadata
- Works at least on Windows, bonus for Mac/Linux
- Drag-and-drop to/from Windows Explorer
- Free, ideally open source

Comment: Shall I suggest [apache cmis workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html) or [ibm content navigator](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/content-navigator) ?

Comment: Yes, could you please create an answer for each, each with a screenshot and your impressions as a user (easy to use or not, fast or not, features you like, etc)? Thanks a lot!